# How can I write these two recipes in one?

Tags: gnu-make, makefile

Here is part of my Makefile

```
bin/shafa: $(OBJDIR)/shafa.o
    $(CC) -g $^ -o "$@"

bin/shafad: $(OBJDIR)/shafad.o
    $(CC) -g $^ -o "$@"
```

I would like to do this in a single recipe. I did something like:

```
bin/shafa%: $(OBJDIR)/shafa%.o
     $(CC) -g $^ -o "$@"
```

But I know it doesn't work because % won't match shafa, only shafad, that's why I wanted something like `*`, the problem is that I don't know how to use this with wildcards.

Answer (score 1):

A pattern must match at least one character, so `shafa%` does not match `shafa`.  But you could just use `shaf%` instead, like this:

```
bin/shaf%: $(OBJDIR)/shaf%.o
        $(CC) -g $^ -o "$@"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer! It does match shafa and shafad but I was looking for something which only matched that, because in this case it will match shafe and shafi, etc as well. Let's supposed I don't want that

Comment: Then you can't use a pattern rule.  If you have a specific set of known targets you want to match, you can use a _static pattern rule_ instead: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Pattern.html